# Solr indexing mysql and search

Tags: mysql, search, solr, lucene

I want to index my database table. If I run in my browser: `http://localhost:8983/solr/dataimport?command=full-import` it returns:

```xml
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="command">full-import</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <lst name="initArgs">
        <lst name="defaults">
            <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
            <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
            <str name="df">text</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <str name="command">full-import</str>
    <str name="status">idle</str>
    <str name="importResponse"/>
    <lst name="statusMessages">
        <str name="Total Requests made to DataSource">21</str>
        <str name="Total Rows Fetched">743</str>
        <str name="Total Documents Skipped">0</str>
        <str name="Full Dump Started">2012-07-02 18:52:47</str>
        <str name="">Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 20 documents. Deleted 0 documents.</str>
        <str name="Committed">2012-07-02 18:52:57</str>
        <str name="Total Documents Processed">20</str><str name="Time taken">0:0:9.977</str>
    </lst>
    <str name="WARNING">This response format is experimental.  It is likely to change in the future.</str>
</response>
```

If I run `http://localhost:8983/solr/select/?q=pasticceria` it return this **ERROR**

> HTTP ERROR 400
>
> Problem accessing /solr/select/. Reason:
>
> Missing solr core name in path

This is my configuration file:

**data-config.xml**

```xml
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
            driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://myhost/mydb"
            user="myuser"
            password="mypsw"/>
<document name="doc">
    <entity name="place" query="SELECT * FROM Place">
        <field column="id_place" name="id_place" />
        <field column="name_place" name="name_place" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

**schema.xml**

```xml
<fields>

   <field name="id_place" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
   <field name="name_place" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <dynamicField name="*" type="ignored" multiValued="true" />
 </fields>

 <uniqueKey>id_place</uniqueKey>
 <defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

**solrconfig.xml**

```xml
  <requestHandler name="/dataimport" class="org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <str name="config">data-config.xml</str>
   <str name="df">text</str>
 </lst>
```

Comment: Wow, that was a long single line of xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to the error message you are using a multicore setup, you need to put the core in the url (imagine its called core0):

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core0/select/?q=pasticceria
```